# Multiple file type uploads to S3 using single Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless

I'd like a user to be able to upload either JPG or PNG image to an S3 bucket.

I am using a Lambda function which allows me to only presign `.jpg` images for S3 and it works great for just one file type. How do I add an additional file type to presign, for example, `.png` images too. Do I really need to write a new Lambda where I just change the `.jpg` to `.png` or I can do it somehow in my existing code below?

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
AWS.config.update({ region: process.env.REGION })
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const uploadBucket = 'xxx-bucket'

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const result = await getUploadURL()
  console.log('Result: ', result)
  return result
};

const getUploadURL = async function() {
  console.log('getUploadURL started')
  let actionId = Date.now()

  var s3Params = {
    Bucket: uploadBucket,
    Key:  `${actionId}.jpg`,
    ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
    CacheControl: 'max-age=31104000',
    ACL: 'public-read',
  };

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Get signed URL
    let uploadURL = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params)
    resolve({
      "statusCode": 200,
      "isBase64Encoded": false,
      "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },
      "body": JSON.stringify({
          "uploadURL": uploadURL,
          "photoFilename": `${actionId}.jpg`
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Items in `s3Params` will be enforced for the upload since they are part of the signed portion. Therefore, try removing `Key:  '${actionId}.jpg'` and `ContentType: 'image/jpeg'`. That should allow anything to be uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are as follow :

- Make a new Lambda as you suggested to handle the PNG separately
- Pass parameters to your `getUploadURL` function through your event, something like :

```
exports.handler = async event => {
  const { filetype } = event.body (or pathParams, query string, etc)
  const result = await getUploadURL(filetype)
  console.log('Result: ', result)
  return result
};

const getUploadURL = async filetype => {
  console.log('getUploadURL started')
  let actionId = Date.now()

  var s3Params = {
    Bucket: uploadBucket,
    Key:  `${actionId}.${filetype}`,
    ContentType: `image/${filetype === 'jpg'?'jpeg':'png'}`,
    CacheControl: 'max-age=31104000',
    ACL: 'public-read',
  };

...
```

The call to S3.getSignedUrl() requires `{Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key'}` at a minimum for a putObject operation. So if you don't want to sacrifice the filename extension and/or the content-type attribute, those are the only options.

[AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property)